# How to add a set border radius?

Tags: javascript, css

I was looking around the web and saw a post about having the img and the quote to change each time the page is refresh and it was on stack overflow 
here is the code to that, credit goes to the original developer but I just want to know where I can add the class img-circle so that it would work in css to have the circular border for the images, sorry this is my first post in Stackoverflow

```
(function() {
  var quotes = [
    {
      text: "text1",
      img:  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBE6.jpg?s=32&g=1"
    },
    {
      text: "text2",
      img:  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
    }
  ];
  var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
    '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
    '<img src="' + quote.img + '">';
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to `img` code :

```
'<img class="img-circle" src="' + quote.img + '">';
```

Full code :

```
(function() {
  var quotes = [
    {
      text: "text1",
      img:  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBE6.jpg?s=32&g=1"
    },
    {
      text: "text2",
      img:  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
    }
  ];
  var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
    '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
    '<img class="img-circle" src="' + quote.img + '">';
})();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
(function() {
  var quotes = [
    {
      text: "text1",
      img:  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBE6.jpg?s=32&g=1"
    },
    {
      text: "text2",
      img:  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
    }
  ];
  var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
    '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
    '<img class="img-circle" src="' + quote.img + '">';
})();
```

```css
.img-circle{
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="quote"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a style attribute inside the img tag with a set border-radius.

```
'<img src="' + quote.img + '" style="border-radius: 100%;">';
```

Answer (score 0):

add the class name in your html tag itself like `class="circle-image"`

```js
(function() {
  var quotes = [
    {
      text: "text1",
      img:  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBE6.jpg?s=32&g=1"
    },
    {
      text: "text2",
      img:  "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca3e484c121268e4c8302616b2395eb9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG",
    }
  ];
  var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
    '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
    '<img src="' + quote.img + '" class="circle-image">';
})();
```

```css
.circle-image{
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="quote"></div>
```